# "Make this anonymous inner class a lambda" code smell in SonarLint

Tags: java, sonarqube, spring-data-mongodb, sonarlint

While checking up the SonarLint report, I am getting this code smell *"Make this anonymous inner class a lambda"* a number of times.
How can I make this inner class as lambda? It is bit challenging for me. How do I resolve this, these are my affected codes.

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(

        new AggregationOperation() {

            @Override
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceDetails, new Document(arrayElemAt,
                        Arrays.asList(new Document(objToArray, rootResourseDetails), 1L))));
            }

        }, new AggregationOperation() {

            @Override
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceDetails, resourceDeatilsV));
            }

        }, LookupOperation.newLookup().from(resourceDetailsStr).localField(resourceDetails).foreignField("_id")
                .as(resourceDetails),
        new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceDetails,
                        new Document(arrayElemAt, Arrays.asList(resourcedetailsTempString, 0L))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(domainStr, new Document(arrayElemAt,
                        Arrays.asList(new Document(objToArray, resourceDetailsDomain), 1L))));
            }
        }

        , new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(domainStr, domainV));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(lookup, new Document("from", "infra_asset")
                        .append("let", new Document(assetIdStr, assetRefId).append(domainStr, rootDomain))
                        .append(pipeLineStr,
                                Arrays.asList(new Document(match, new Document(expr, new Document("$and",
                                        Arrays.asList(new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(domain, infra)),
                                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$_id", assetId))))))))
                        .append("as", "infraAssest"));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(lookup, new Document("from", "application_asset")
                        .append("let", new Document(assetIdStr, assetRefId).append(domainStr, rootDomain))
                        .append(pipeLineStr,
                                Arrays.asList(new Document(match, new Document(expr, new Document("$and",
                                        Arrays.asList(new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(domain, "Application")),
                                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$_id", assetId))))))))
                        .append("as", applicationAsset));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(project, new Document(resourceDetails, 1L).append(resourceThresholdStr, 1L)
                        .append(customFieldStr, new Document(cond, new Document("if",
                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(rootDomain, infra)))
                                .append("then", rootInfraAsset)
                                .append("else", new Document(cond,
                                        new Document("if",
                                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(rootDomain, application)))
                                                .append("then", rootApplicationAsset)
                                                .append("else", "null"))))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(customFieldStr,
                        new Document(arrayElemAt, Arrays.asList(customField, 0L))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(match, new Document(expr, new Document("$and",
                        Arrays.asList(new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(customFieldPlatformName, platformName)),
                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(customFieldAssetName, assetName))))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(moduleStr, new Document(arrayElemAt,
                        Arrays.asList(new Document(objToArray, resourceDetailModule), 1L))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(moduleStr, moduleV));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(lookup, new Document("from", modulesStr).append(localFieldStr, moduleStr)
                        .append(foreignFieldStr, "_id").append("as", moduleStr));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields,
                        new Document(moduleStr, new Document(arrayElemAt, Arrays.asList(module, 0L))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(match,
                        new Document(expr, new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(moduleString, moduleName))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {

                return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceThresholdStr, new Document(arrayElemAt,
                        Arrays.asList(new Document(objToArray, "$$ROOT.resourceThreshold"), 1L))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceThresholdStr, "$resourceThreshold.v"));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(lookup,
                        new Document("from", "resource_threshold").append(localFieldStr, resourceThresholdStr)
                                .append(foreignFieldStr, "_id").append("as", resourceThresholdStr));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceThresholdStr,
                        new Document(arrayElemAt, Arrays.asList("$resourceThreshold", 0L))));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(addFields, new Document(platformNameStr, customFieldPlatformName)
                        .append("asset_name", customFieldAssetName).append(moduleNameStr, moduleString));
            }
        }, new AggregationOperation() {
            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new Document(project, new Document(moduleNameStr, 1L).append(resourceThresholdStr, 1L)
                        .append(platformNameStr, 1L).append("asset_name", 1L));
            }
        }

);
```

Every block starting from `new AggregationOperation` is affected.

Comment: I think the complaint might be one of the lesser problems with the code here :(

Comment: I suggest researching what lambda expressions are and how you can translate an anonymous class into a lambda expression. There are many tutorials on the internet. Once you understand how it all works, making the changes to your code should be relatively easy (if maybe a little tedious). Though it may make more sense to refactor these operations into methods so that they're "named", and then use method references instead of lambda expressions.

Comment: If you have a good IDE, it will even suggest to refactor it (convert to lambda or something like that), and accepting that suggestion it will do it for you. That said, just because something can be refactored to a lambda, doesn't mean you must do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
new AggregationOperation() {

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceDetails, new Document(arrayElemAt,
        Arrays.asList(new Document(objToArray, rootResourseDetails), 1L))));
    }
}
```

You should just be able to write

```
context -> new Document(addFields, new Document(resourceDetails, new Document(arrayElemAt,
        Arrays.asList(new Document(objToArray, rootResourseDetails), 1L))))
```

and similarly for every `AggregationOperation` that you create.

This is because the compiler can figure out that you need an `AggregationOperation` and understands that an `AggregationOperation` has only one method.  That's why you can replace the anonymous `AggregationOperation` with the lambda equivalent of that method.

You might like to look into whether your IDE can do this refactoring for you automatically.