# Code Smell : Make this anonymous inner class a lambda

Tags: java, function, lambda

```
public Transformer getTransformed(Locale locale, SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
    return new Transformer() {
        public Object transform(Object o) {
            Tag tag = (Tag) o;

            String tagId = tag.getTagID();
            ValueMap vm = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap<>());
            vm.put("value", tagId);
            vm.put("text", tag.getTitlePath(locale));
            return new ValueMapResource(request.getResourceResolver(), new ResourceMetadata(), "nt:unstructured", vm);
        }
    };
}
```

[image]
I have the above function and I got a code smell that says `" Make this anonymous inner class a lambda "` .

Now I am not sure how to convert this to a lambda function because of the putting of value in valuemap.
How to convert the above function into a lambda function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Make this anonymous inner class a lambda" code smell in SonarLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72255016/make-this-anonymous-inner-class-a-lambda-code-smell-in-sonarlint)

Comment: `Transformer` is an interface? Only interfaces could be implemented using lambda expressions, and `transform()` should be the only abstract method.

Comment: Keep in mind that avoiding side-effects is something that's asked moreso of `java.util.Stream` usage, rather than lambdas wholesale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need, no need to create an object of a some class:

```
Function<Object, Object> transform = o -> {
        Tag tag = (Tag) o;

        String tagId = tag.getTagID();
        ValueMap vm = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap<>());
        vm.put("value", tagId);
        vm.put("text", tag.getTitlePath(locale));
        return new ValueMapResource(request.getResourceResolver(), new ResourceMetadata(), "nt:unstructured", vm);

    };
```

Comment: I would say it'd be more appropriate to use a `Transformer` on the left, as that's what OP's method is expecting. While the functional interface signatures would match, it's still something that might hiccup if you put it in directly like this.

Comment: The point is to not return an inner class object no ? I honestly was only answering the part of transforming a lambda. I think OP should use a transformer factory.

Comment: Well, you can assign the lambda to the `Transformer` class directly: `Transformer t = o -> {...}`, as it is reducible to a functional interface. You can also just return the lambda itself: `return o -> {...};`